# Which are the conditions for a biquadratic equation to have $~4~$ different roots?

Tags: roots, quadratics

Which are the conditions for a biquadratic equation to have $~4~$ different roots in $~\mathbb R~$? I think $~D>0~$, If we have $$t=x^2$$ then $~t>0~$. Is there any other condition?

Comment: A polynomial equation $f(x)=0$ has no multiple roots if $\gcd(f,f')=1$.

Answer (score 0):

A biquadratic equation is of the form $$~ax^4 +bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e = 0~.$$

It has at maximum $~4~$ roots. All the roots will be real (according to OP's question) if the graph of the equation $$~f(x)= ax^4 +bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e~$$ cuts the $~x$-axis at $~4~$ points. This means that it forms $~3~$ loops with the $~x$-axis. This also means that it has $~3~$ extreme points i.e. the points of local maxima or minima. Now, at every such point the tangent to the function $~f(x)~$ becomes horizontal or $~f'(x)=0~$.

The derivative of $f(x)$, $$~f'(x)= (4a)x^3+(3b)x^2+(2c)x+d~.$$

Now if the equation $$~f'(x)=(4a)x^3+(3b)x^2+(2c)x+d=0$$ has $~3~$ real and distinct roots then we conclude that $~f'(x)=0~$ for $~3~$ distinct values. This also means that $~f(x)~$ has $~3~$ different points at which the tangent to it is horizontal. This further means that it forms $~3~$ loops and hence cuts the $~x$-axis at $~4~$ different points which ensures all roots are real.

Hence, **the condition for a biquadratic equation $~f(x)=0~$ to have all real roots is that it's first derivative $~f'(x)=0~$ must have $~3~$ real and distinct roots.**

---

**Rolle’s Theorem**

Suppose that a function $~f(x)~$ is continuous on the closed interval $~[a,b]~$ and differentiable on the open interval$~(a,b)~$. Then if $~f\left( a \right) = f\left( b \right),~$
 then there exists at least one point $~c~$ in the open interval such that $~f'(c)=0~$.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The biquadratic polynomial $ax^4+bx^2+c$ will have four distinct roots precisely if $at^2+bt+c=0$ has two distinct roots (since distinct numbers can't have identical square roots) and these two roots are $\not= 0$. This happens if and only if $b^2-4ac\not=0$ and $c\not= 0$.